# Adding transition effect to a background-image change on a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm changing the background-image of a div using jquery+css like this:

```js
var slide_images = ["http://foodnetwork.sndimg.com/content/dam/images/food/fullset/2014/2/7/1/FNM_030114-Spaghetti-Carbonara-Recipe-h_s4x3.jpg", "http://www.labrasseriefirenze.it/labrasserie/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/spaghetti-carbonara.jpg"];
var slide_count = 0;


$(document).ready(function() {

      setInterval(function() {
          slide_count=++slide_count%slide_images.length;

          $('.slide_photo').css('background-image', 'url(\''+slide_images[slide_count]+'\')');
          }, 4000);

});
```

```css
.slide_photo {
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url('http://foodnetwork.sndimg.com/content/dam/images/food/fullset/2014/2/7/1/FNM_030114-Spaghetti-Carbonara-Recipe-h_s4x3.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  transition: all .2s ease;
}
.slide_photo:hover {
  background-size: 110% auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slide_photo"></div>
```

**The question is**: Is it possible to add a fade-in effect or transition to make the change smoother than it is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about some css3 animation like this

```
.slide_photo{
  -webkit-animation: fade 4s infinite;
  -moz-animation: fade 4s infinite;
  -o-animation: fade 4s infinite;
  animation: fade 4s infinite;
}

.slide_photo {
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url('http://foodnetwork.sndimg.com/content/dam/images/food/fullset/2014/2/7/1/FNM_030114-Spaghetti-Carbonara-Recipe-h_s4x3.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  -webkit-animation: fade 4s infinite;
  -moz-animation: fade 4s infinite;
  -o-animation: fade 4s infinite;
  animation: fade 4s infinite;
}
.slide_photo:hover {
  background-size: 110% auto;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```js
var slide_images = ["http://foodnetwork.sndimg.com/content/dam/images/food/fullset/2014/2/7/1/FNM_030114-Spaghetti-Carbonara-Recipe-h_s4x3.jpg", "http://www.labrasseriefirenze.it/labrasserie/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/spaghetti-carbonara.jpg"];
var slide_count = 0;


$(document).ready(function() {

  setInterval(function() {
    slide_count = ++slide_count % slide_images.length;

    $('.slide_photo').css('background-image', 'url(\'' + slide_images[slide_count] + '\')');
  }, 4000);

});
```

```css
.slide_photo {
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url('http://foodnetwork.sndimg.com/content/dam/images/food/fullset/2014/2/7/1/FNM_030114-Spaghetti-Carbonara-Recipe-h_s4x3.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  -webkit-animation: fade 4s infinite;
  -moz-animation: fade 4s infinite;
  -o-animation: fade 4s infinite;
  animation: fade 4s infinite;
}
.slide_photo:hover {
  background-size: 110% auto;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slide_photo"></div>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for Dhiraj, pure css magic. Thanks! The only problem is that sometimes the fade-in of the new image is not perfectly synchronized with the image change. So what is happening is that on the new fade-in, just for a second, the previous image is still visible.

Comment: An the more the slideshow keeps going, the more this problem shows up. :\

Comment: probably because the 4s delay is different in JS and CSS. Maybe the  animation should be entirely in CSS or in JS.

Comment: Is it possible to do the CSS animation of your answer just on click?

Comment: Yes. Move all the css3 animations to a separate class. In the click handler add that class.